# Use map_server inside Docker : node won't launch

Tags: navigation, mapping, docker, map-server, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working with this [tutorial](https://github.com/osrf/car_demo) to simulate an environment and test my sensors set to benchmark localization and navigation algorithms.
I can launch the tutorial with my custom world and sensors, that's okay ; but I can't find a way to load a static map in Rviz.
I added a node in the launch file, as usual and the error log is the following:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [map_server/map_server]: map_server
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/tmp/workspace/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

So here I am checking on my computer on these locations if I have the map_server package.  Obviously, as I have already used it before, I found it in

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

However, I know that Docker creates its own container, and loads ROS packages into it. So I fired up a terminal, typed

```
docker ps -l
```

to get the name of the actual docker. Then

```
docker exec -it <docker_container_name> bash
```

to open up an interactive console within the container. Then

```
cd /opt/ros/kinetic/share; ls
```

And here is the trick : there is no map_server package here. So the node can't be launched. Thus, my question is pretty simple: how can I "pass" the map_server package inside the Docker container, or any other package after that, without using a tremendous number of plugins and tricky command lines?

Thank you very much for your help!

Guillaume

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274745/use-map_server-inside-docker-:-node-won%27t-launch/) by [GuillaumeHauss](https://answers.ros.org/users/29510/guillaumehauss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found it!
you need to modify the Dockerfile that create your image. Add this:

```
# setup sources.list
RUN echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list 

# install ros packages
ENV ROS_DISTRO kinetic
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
   ros-kinetic-map-server \
   ros-kinetic-amcl \
   ros-kinetic-hector-slam \
   <any_ros_package> \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

However, this not solve the issue in case of house-made package. So a better, more flexible solution might still be suitable!

---

Originally posted by [GuillaumeHauss](https://answers.ros.org/users/29510/guillaumehauss/) with karma: 36 on 2017-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1